# Записать данные из datetimepicker в span радио кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Частично получилось:
Нажимаем кнопку "указать время" - выбираем время - результат записывается в span радиокнопки
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/GXEYBP?editors=1010

Но пока не получается вывести данные в необходимом формате:

например 05.09.2018 10:00

сейчас там много лишнего, неверный вид и выглядит так (хотя в настройках указал формат даты):
Fri Aug 17 2018 13:00:00 GMT+0800 (Китай, стандартное время)

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что поменять в js коде, или может неправильно настроен плагин

```
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('ru');

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#exact-time").datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
      format: 'd/m/y H:i',
      lang:'ru',
        onSelectDate: function (d) {
            $("span.exact-time__text").text(d);

        }
    });

    $(".exact-time__radio").click(function () {
      // $("span.exact-time__text").text('');
        $("#exact-time").datetimepicker("show");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проинспектировал код. При выборе даты и времени они записываются в `value` input'a в том формате, который вы указали в `format: 'd.m.Y H:i'`. Следовательно их можно достать простой функцией `val()`.

Как я понял при тесте, `onSelectDate` здесь будет не правильным, т.к. он срабатывает только при выборе даты. Покопался в документации плагина, нашел функцию `onChangeDateTime` и изменил на нее, она срабатывает всегда.
Рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/vita1ya/pen/yxXrpG